# Setting log4j properties file via JVM argument - why does order matter?

Tags: java, jvm, log4j, config

I have built a jar file which has a `log4j.properties` file in it (`mvn package` put it there by default from the `resources` directory). But when I run this jar file, I want to pass a different logging config, so I add `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:{path to file}`. The issue that bugs me is that the order matters here as follows:

- When I run `java -jar {path to jar} -Dlog4j.configuration=file:{path to file}` then it reads the log file packaged in the jar.
- When I run `java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:{path to file} -jar {path to jar}`, then it reads the config from the file I pass in the parameters.

I have rough understanding how classpaths work in java and that if I were to load several java classes with the same name, it would make a difference. But this way I am passing a config parameter with a `-D` prefix, so the way I expect this to work is for some code in `log4j` library to check whether `-Dlog4j.configuration` is set and if so, then load the config from there, otherwise try to find it on the classpath.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: In case anyone interested, I am using `log4j v1.2.16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide anything after naming the `JAR` file, it is treated as an argument to your `main` method. For Log4J you actually have to define a property, and this needs to be done before you specify `-jar`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot :)